# Set the value of an empty variable sent from another activity to something else than 0 using putExtra() and getExtra()

Tags: android, variables, android-intent

I don't know if this question has been asked before, couldn't find any information about this: **how to set the value of an empty variable sent to another application via putExtra/getExtra to something else than zero by default?**

Let me explain why and show you a little schema to make things clearer:
[image]

As you can see, in my application, I have a method which communicate with a database and sends different informations depending on the button you clicked.  So for every button, I have this kind of code :

```
private OnClickListener listener_button1 = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent t = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                ResultListViewActivity.class);
        t.putExtra("myVariable1", 10);
        t.putExtra("myVariable3", 45);
        t.putExtra("myVariable2", 2);
        t.putExtra("myVariable4", 1000);
        startActivity(t);
```

As I want to make my program as light as possible, I just defined one method for every button, as it's doing the same thing. The problem is, not every button send the same number of variable : some just sends 1 or 2 variables, some sends up to 4 variables. And when it's not sending anything, getExtra() automatically sets the value to 0, which is bad in my case as 0 refers to something specific in my database (I would prefer my variable to be set to 1000 instead, as 1000 doesn't refer to anything in particular).

So what I would like, to sum up, it's not to have to specify everytime I don't use a variable something like this code, and find a way to make it an automatism instead:

```
  t.putExtra("myVariable4", 1000);
```

I already tried to initialize the value like this at the beginning of my activity calling the method, but it doesn't work :
       int variable = 1000 ;

It seems that this part of the code systematically put it to 0 :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    int variable4 = bundle.getInt("variable4");
```

ps: i don't want to manually set all my variables which don't have a specific value because in my real application, it's much more than 4 inputs and 3 buttons so it would be really heavy to have for each button listener a lot of variables set to 1000.
I hope I made it clear enough !

Comment: can't you just say if (bundle.getInt("variable4") != 0) then set the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally its like this:-

```
bundle.getInt("passedVariable", defaultValue);
```

In your case, since the default is `1000`,

`bundle.getInt("variable4", 1000);` should do the trick for you.

For info on [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Comment: Perfect, it indeed does the trick ! Thanks a lot, it's definitely gonna simplify my code.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a default value

```
bundle.getInt("variable4",default-value)
```